# The refreshed AJAX content hidden due to a CSS property

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, handlebars.js

I have an image. On clicking that image I get a pop-up. The contents inside the pop-up are generated by AJAX. I am using handlebars for templating. Since the pop-up should be hidden initially, I have set it's property to `display:none` and I am using toggle to show it on clicking the image. Now, coming to the problem, When I request another JSON using AJAX, I am using ,

```
//get the HTML template from script tag
var theTemplateScript = $("#dynamicData").html();
//compile the template
var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
$("#sg-hb-employee").html(theTemplate(myData[0]));
```

the above code to get the content. I am replacing the html. Since the HTML is added again, the default `display: none` property is getting applied and I can see the new content only on clicking the image, whereas I was it just to be shown there itself without that `display:none` property being applied.

Comment: Have you tried adding JQuery `.css("display","block");` ? so after the `.html` add the `.css` - also could give an example in JSfiddle or something that people can test and give you an answer

Comment: That property isn't getting applied as the entire div is getting added to the DOM again. Do you think a `setTimeout` would help?

Comment: Could you provide a JSfiddle with an example so I could  take a look at what you're doing so far - also you could try adding a `setTimeout` of 1 or 2 seconds

Comment: `setTimeout` worked. :) Thanks for the help Chris. You just add an answer for the sake of it. I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attempt to try and use JQuery `.css()`

```
.css("display","block");

// So it would look like this
.html(data).css("display","block");
```

or you could add a `setTimeout` of 1 or 2 seconds

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    // Add what you need inside this
}, 2000);
```